# How does START_REDELIVER_INTENT behave with multiple Intents?

Tags: android, android-service

If a Service has multiple calls to `startService()` using different Intents, how does it behave with `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` when the application is restarted after being killed due to low memory?

Example: I call `startService(intent, class)` three times with different `Intents`. Before the Service stops itself, the OS kills the application or the Service due to memory usage. Later, the Service returns. According to `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` `onStartCommand()` should be called with the original Intent that started it. Will it be called for all three? Only the first one? Only the last one?

I thought about testing it, but I want to know what is *supposed* to happen, not just what my specific device does. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's supposed to redeliver all those that you did not mark as completed via the one-parameter version of `stopSelf()`. The [docs for it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) are murky on the topic, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it be called for all three? Only the first one? Only the last
>   one?

**Only the last one.**

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) is pretty clear about this:

*...if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from `onStartCommand()`), then it will be scheduled for a restart and the last delivered Intent re-delivered to
 it again via `onStartCommand()`.*

Answer (score 4):

the answer adopted is not correct.

He did not see the next few words:

> This Intent will remain scheduled for redelivery until the service calls {@link #stopSelf(int)} with the start ID provided to {@link #onStartCommand}

it means that when an intent comes and `onStartCommand` called, if we don't stopSelf the `onStartCommand`'s startId associated with the intent, the system treats this intent as `not-handled`, So then when service re-create, these `not-handled` intents will re-delivered to `onStartCommand`.

So, it will be called three times.